# Parsing data from JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON file output as below

```
{
  u'_embedded': {
u'workouts': [
  {
    u'start_datetime': u'2015-02-16T08:47:00+00:00',
    u'name': u'Walk',
    u'updated_datetime': u'2015-02-16T19:20:36+00:00',
    u'created_datetime': u'2015-02-16T19:20:36+00:00',
    u'notes': u'',
    u'reference_key': None,
    u'start_locale_timezone': u'Europe/London',
    u'source': None,
    u'_links': {
      u'user': [
        {
          u'href': u'/v7.1/user/******/',
          u'id': u'******'
        }
      ],
      u'self': [
        {
          u'href': u'/v7.1/workout/*******/',
          u'id': u'*******'
        }
      ],
      u'privacy': [
        {
          u'href': u'/v7.1/privacy_option/1/',
          u'id': u'1'
        }
      ],
      u'route': [
        {
          u'href': u'/v7.1/route/*******/',
          u'id': u'*******'
        }
      ],
      u'activity_type': [
        {
          u'href': u'/v7.1/activity_type/9/',
          u'id': u'9'
        }
      ]
    },
    u'has_time_series': False,
    u'is_verified': False,
    u'aggregates': {
      u'active_time_total': 1020.0,
      u'elapsed_time_total': 1020.0,
      u'distance_total': 1729.99651968,
      u'speed_avg': 1.6972231232,
      u'steps_total': 0.0
    }
  }
]
  },
  u'_links': {
u'self': [
  {
    u'href': u'/v7.1/workout/?limit=20&user=******&offset=0'
  }
],
u'documentation': [
  {
    u'href': u'https://developer.underarmour.com/docs/v71_Workout'
  }
]
  },
  u'total_count': 1
}
```

From this code, I wish to pull the workout id on it's own, which is in the

```
u'user': [
    {
      u'href': u'/v7.1/user/******/',
      u'id': u'******'
    }
```

I've managed it using json.loads in a different piece of code, although as in my code below, I am not sure how to implement it so I can use json.loads instead of x.json() as I am using, so I've become lost. I've attempted to do it as I would using json.loads by using indexes, but it just throws an error. Below is a snippet of the code and what I have attempted

```
route = requests.get(url='https://oauth2-api.mapmyapi.com/v7.1/workout/?user=********', verify=False,
                    headers={'api-key': CLIENT_ID, 'authorization': 'Bearer %s' % access_token['access_token']})

route = route.json()

for info in route['workouts']['self']:
print info['id']

#print route
```

Any help as to how to pull the data from the JSON would be hugely appreciated, or how to edit my code to allow me to use json.loads instead.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not JSON, it's a Python dictionary.

Comment: What error you are getting when you use `json.loads` ?

Comment: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a python dict object you use proper keys to get the values. 
From the dictionary you provided, if the the dictionary is d then.

```
itm = d.get(u'_embedded').get(u'workouts')[0]
```

itm is,

```
{u'_links': {u'activity_type': [{u'href': u'/v7.1/activity_type/9/',
    u'id': u'9'}],
  u'privacy': [{u'href': u'/v7.1/privacy_option/1/', u'id': u'1'}],
  u'route': [{u'href': u'/v7.1/route/*******/', u'id': u'*******'}],
  u'self': [{u'href': u'/v7.1/workout/*******/', u'id': u'*******'}],
  u'user': [{u'href': u'/v7.1/user/******/', u'id': u'******'}]},
 u'aggregates': {u'active_time_total': 1020.0,
  u'distance_total': 1729.99651968,
  u'elapsed_time_total': 1020.0,
  u'speed_avg': 1.6972231232,
  u'steps_total': 0.0},
 u'created_datetime': u'2015-02-16T19:20:36+00:00',
 u'has_time_series': False,
 u'is_verified': False,
 u'name': u'Walk',
 u'notes': u'',
 u'reference_key': None,
 u'source': None,
 u'start_datetime': u'2015-02-16T08:47:00+00:00',
 u'start_locale_timezone': u'Europe/London',
 u'updated_datetime': u'2015-02-16T19:20:36+00:00'}
```

get the user information:

```
 print itm.get(u'_links').get(u'user')

 [{u'href': u'/v7.1/user/******/', u'id': u'******'}]
```

now get get id:

```
print itm.get(u'_links').get(u'user')[0].get(u'id')
******
```

You might iterate over the list instead of using index value.

Answer (score 1):

That is not JSON. Its a Python dictionary. Do you see: single quotes for strings and `u'blah blah'`? That's not JSON. They are python object representations.

Use `ast.literal_eval` to parse everything back from a string to a python object.

```
>>> import ast
>>> with open('input') as f:
...     obj = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
...
>>> obj
{u'_links': ......... } #Your entire object appears here.
>>> for item in obj["_embedded"]["workouts"]:
...     print item["_links"]["user"]
...
[{u'href': u'/v7.1/user/******/', u'id': u'******'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is already a Python dict. It is not JSON and there is no need to load it.

Comment: So given that it isn't JSON, how would I extract just the value I want from it?